# What is the spring validation of the configuration?

Tags: java, spring, validation

I was reading the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-dependency-resolution) and came across the following text:

> The Spring container validates the configuration of each bean as the
> container is created.

To me, it's not quite clear what they meant the Spring container validates the configuration? In our project we have `xml`-configuration file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- beans -->

</beans
```

Is it just an `xml`-validation with respect to the schema-location defined within the tag `bean` or what? Couldn't you explain?

What is the validation going to be if we provide a Java or annotation-based configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation is more or less the same regardless of the way you configure your `ApplicationContext`. The validation simply consists of an initial check of the bean relationships. For example, if you declare a bean `firstBean` which references a bean `secondBean` in one of its properties, but `secondBean` isn't declared in the context, then that will cause the container to fail before it even tries to initialize the beans themselves.

Comment: So, the xml-validation is being performed before the bean-validation

Comment: Yes, that's part of the parsing.